# How to toggle content in Semantic UI buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, semantic-ui

The [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html) says *a button can be formatted to toggle on or off*, but the example given is merely

```
<div class="ui toggle button">
    Vote
</div>
```

which naturally, doesn't work. An inspection of the source code of the example reveals an `active` class is programmatically added.

I'm probably missing something simple, but how can I create a toggle button like in that example? What's the syntax for specifying what to toggle between?

Comment: hope u have included required semantic js file, they have been adding classes programmatically only.

Comment: oh, of course. What I don't know is the syntax to specify what to toggle between.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The below code is doing the magic:

```
semantic.button = {};

// ready event
semantic.button.ready = function() {

  // selector cache
  var
    $buttons = $('.ui.buttons .button'),
    $toggle  = $('.main .ui.toggle.button'),
    $button  = $('.ui.button').not($buttons).not($toggle),
    // alias
    handler = {

      activate: function() {
        $(this)
          .addClass('active')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active')
        ;
      }

    }
  ;

  $buttons
    .on('click', handler.activate)
  ;


  $toggle
    .state({
      text: {
        inactive : 'Vote',
        active   : 'Voted'
      }
    })
  ;

};


// attach ready event
$(document)
  .ready(semantic.button.ready)
;
```

Comment: Thanks, they should really document this properly, and make it more compact to specify all this.

Comment: Agreed, I was confused why it wasn't working either. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Would be useful if you put up a jsfiddle or something similar to show this working as this does not work for me

Comment: @Huey, it is mostly one guy writing the Semantic-UI framework, take it easy, bro. Anyone can improve the docs, just fork the repo, edit, and make a pull request.

Comment: This will not work unless you also have `semantic = {};` somewhere.  You'll get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: semantic`.  Why not include `semantic = {};`?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get the toggle buttons working without any options etc is the following:

```
$('.ui.button.toggle').state();
```

This should toggle between the default grey and green colors on click. See the other answers for more complicated behaviour. Make sure the DOM etc is loaded first as with other semantic UI initializers.

Comment: `<script src="components/state.js"></script>` I had to include state js from semantic components - https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/blob/master/components/state.js
Alternatively use `state.min.js`. This seems to be the most suitable answer since it is using semantic API, rather than using non semantic code to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple,

```
<button class="ui toggle button active" id="tgl">Toogle button</button>
```

just use the classic jquery click to toogle the active class, and add any other changes you need. I think that using semantic stage is a waste of time in this case.

```
$('#tgl').click(function(){      
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following simple code is working fine for two different toggle buttons with onClick event. Thank you Mukesh for inspiring me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dist/semantic.css">
<script src="../assets/library/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/semantic.js"></script>

</head>
<script>

function show(b){
alert( $(b).hasClass("active"));
}

// attach ready event
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
  var $toggle  = $('.ui.toggle.button');
  $toggle
    .state({
      text: {
        inactive : 'Vote',
        active   : 'Voted'
      }
    })
  ;

})
;
</script>
<body>

<button class="ui toggle button" onclick="show(this)">
  Vote
</button>
<br/><br/>
<button class="ui toggle button" onclick="show(this)">
  Vote
</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I just simplify the answer for whom may is looking for the same issue, as I had trouble with Mukesh answer, however it inspired me as I said :)