# How to make Semantic UI button group selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uibutton, semantic-ui

How do I make the Semantic UI [Button Group](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html#buttons) selectable so that I can get the one that's selected in PHP?

Here is the button group:

```
<div class="huge ui buttons">
  <div class="ui button">One</div>
  <div class="ui button">Two</div>
  <div class="ui button">Three</div>
</div>
```

I would assume we are to treat the buttons like radio buttons where only one can be selected but Semantic UI doesn't really have any documentation on how to do the same with button groups.

How would I make the buttons selectable so I can send it to my PHP script?

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cgz7sv4g) is a jsFiddle showing how my button groups at the moment after trying to implement the toggle as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032833/how-to-toggle-content-in-semantic-ui-buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a button is pressed *Semantic UI* gives that button a class name called `active`.

To select from your group you could do:

```
var selected = document.querySelector(".huge.ui.buttons").querySelector(".active");
```

This will select the UI group with the first part and returns the selected element with the second part. You can perform actions on the selected element like `selected.textContent`. This will return the display text of the element.

---

Since you've tagged jQuery, I will provide a jQuery example too:

```
var selected = $(".huge.ui.buttons").find(".active");
```

> **NOTE:** Please not that you will likely create multiple groups with the same class names (`huge ui buttons`). You will need to discriminate between them. Either use `document.querySelectorAll` and select the proper element using its `index` or give every group a unique ID so you can access the group with `document.getElementById`.
>
> **NOTE 2:** Semantic isn't documenting this, but they use additional code on their page to set the button to active. You can find it here. [How to toggle content in Semantic UI buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032833/how-to-toggle-content-in-semantic-ui-buttons). I modified it to work with your Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cgz7sv4g/2/

---

Addon to *Semantic UI*:

```
semantic = {};
// ready event
semantic.ready = function() {

  // selector cache
  var
    $buttons = $('.ui.buttons .button'),
    $toggle  = $('.main .ui.toggle.button'),
    $button  = $('.ui.button').not($buttons).not($toggle),
    // alias
    handler = {

      activate: function() {
        $(this)
          .addClass('active')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active')
        ;
      }

    }
  ;

  $buttons
    .on('click', handler.activate)
  ;


// attach ready event
$(document)
  .ready(semantic.ready)
;
```

This block of code will extend your Semantic Buttons with a handler that adds the class `active` to currently clicked element and removes it from other elements in the group. You can extend *Semantic UI's* elements with this code. using basic jQuery, since *Semantic UI* is a platform build upon jQuery.

EDIT:

---

To send the content of the *div* in through a form request

- needed a hidden input

Javascript

```
 var selected = $(".huge.ui.buttons").find(".active").text();
 $("#div_content").val(selected);
```

Comment: The problem is that Semantic UI is not giving the button an active class when I select something. Am I missing a piece of JavaScript that actually makes a button active?

Comment: @user3574492 does the appearance of the button change, like in the example page you've mentioned?

Comment: No, it only has an onmousedown state, when I select a button the appearance doesn't change.

Comment: I have tried to implement the piece of code from the link and it does nothing Here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cgz7sv4g/

Comment: @user3574492, the updated Fiddle (as well as the code in the post) should solve your problem.

Comment: The fiddle still doesn't work, the buttons are not being selected.

Comment: Ah I see now it works, so how do I now check if one of the buttons is selected through PHP, for radio buttons I normally use `if(isset($_POST[''])...`

Comment: @user3574492 A post can work. Do you use ajax or forms?

Comment: Currently using forms

Comment: @user3574492 use a hidden input in which you save the variable from the div.

Comment: So I can't actually use POST to get the direct value because it's technically not an input right?

Comment: @user3574492, no you can't because forms only submit form elements, so you need to put a intermediary between it, ergo `<input type="hidden" value="[div]" />`

Comment: What do I actually put in the `value=""`?

Comment: @user3574492, the text value of the div (anything you want).

Comment: But I have to get the value of the selected button  in JavaScript right? e.g. `selected.textContent`? and then insert that into the div

Comment: @user3574492 I have edit my question, that should suffice for the thing you need (Answer in jQuery).